# Monitor detection fails with amdgpu-pro

Tags: 16.04, radeon, monitor, amdgpu

I bought a Radeon RX560 and try to install it on xubuntu 16.04.
First i installed amdgpu-pro as described by amd.
Everything worked fine with 1 Monitor (DVI - FullHD).

Then i plugged in the second one (HDMI - FullHD) and the display is mirrored.
But in preferences->Display is only 1 Monitor visible. 
So i collected some information:

```
lspci -nn | grep "VGA"
```

outputs:

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:67ff] (rev cf)

I would expected something like "Radeon RX560"? Why not?
[Solution:] After "sudo update-pciids" i see now: [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 560]

Next step was:

```
sudo lshw -c display
```

output:

```
 *-display               
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   Hersteller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   Physische ID: 0
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
   Version: cf
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   Konfiguration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   Ressourcen: irq:27 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dfe00000-dfffffff ioport:ee00(Größe=256) memory:fdd80000-fddbffff memory:fdd00000-fdd1ffff
```

Why only one device if i have a picture on both monitors?

and finally xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00*

no gamma? Not good i think.

And xrandr --listprovider has no results. 0 Entrys..

[Edit:]
It seems my Xorg conf is wrong. I got the Error:

```
[     6.049] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Oct 28 16:25:43 2017
[     6.050] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     6.050] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     6.050] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     6.050] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     6.050] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     6.051] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
 Using a default monitor configuration.
```

I will try to fix it and post the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, why run the amdgpu-pro driver? I just plugged in my RX580 and all 3 monitors were up and running.

Comment: Not in my case :(

Comment: Because the generic drivers are not running smooth